# Handsontable(6.2.2) manualColumnMove not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, handsontable

I want to change column display position by array(DB saved).

```
//data ex.        def. pos
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
 /*...*/
 columns:[    
    {data: 'A'}, //0
    {data: 'B'}, //1
    {data: 'C'}, //2
    {data: 'D'}, //3
    {data: 'E'}  //4
]);
```

Save Array example.

```
    arrPos = [2,4,1,3,0]; // want to show col line is, C, E, B, D, A
```

I wrote hot setting is,

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
 /*...*/
 manualColumnMove: arrPos 
/*...*/
});
```

But, display is A, B, C, D, E(not change). Please help.

Comment: Added.
Can't change default line, need dynamic change.

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems as expected in v6.2.2 (tested on CE, but PRO works the same) https://jsfiddle.net/v6zj9mru/1/
When `colHeaders` are set to `true` they do not move, but once you change them to any given array they stick to the moved column.